# I accidentally ran the mkfs.ntfs command on a wrong device, and stopped it

Tags: linux, sd-card

as I said, I accidentally ran the mkfs.ntfs command on a wrong device, and stopped it when it was at 8%, now the device is inaccessible. Is there is any way I can recover what was on that devic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will spare you the lecture about keeping backups.

There are some ways of recovering some of the data.

The very first thing that you need to do is make a copy of the device. Use

```
dd if=/dev/device of=some_file
```

The reason is, that when you try to recover, you may accidentally destroy data. If you work on the copy, you can just create a new copy. If you work on the original, it is gone.

You may try `testdisk`, especially if it was an extfs partition. Maybe it can locate a backup superblock and you can work from there.

If not, software like `photorec` may be able to restore some of your pictures. Other tools exist.

Beware though: if your `mkfs.ntfs` is at 8%, you have lost an awful lot of data that cannot just be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `mkfs` probably overwrote the partition table. You'll need lots of luck to restore :-(

You can try `testdisk` (https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk, `apt-get install testdisk`) to restore your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recover data in my experience R-Studio Undelete is the best product on the market. Just recently a guy from Stack Exchange managed to recover over 100K photos using it. This is not an advertisement.

Native Linux tools like photorec/testdisk are very basic and often don't help at all.